# How to interpolate data in R

Tags: r

I am quite new to R Studio and I have a question:

I have the following data: (Date; Time; Value)

```
02.01.11;11:00;576
02.01.11;11:05;552
02.01.11;11:10;672
02.01.11;11:15;720
02.01.11;11:20;336
02.01.11;11:25;408
02.01.11;11:30;288
02.01.11;11:35;228
02.01.11;11:40;288
02.01.11;11:45;288
02.01.11;11:50;288
02.01.11;11:55;312
02.01.11;12:00;180
02.01.11;12:05;120
02.01.11;12:10;120
02.01.11;12:15;228
02.01.11;12:20;276
02.01.11;12:25;228
02.01.11;12:30;444
02.01.11;12:35;612
02.01.11;12:40;300
02.01.11;12:45;288
02.01.11;12:50;300
02.01.11;12:55;336
02.01.11;13:00;240
02.01.11;13:05;252
02.01.11;13:10;192
02.01.11;13:15;180
02.01.11;13:20;192
02.01.11;13:25;432
02.01.11;13:30;912
02.01.11;13:35;960
02.01.11;13:40;936
02.01.11;13:45;1260
02.01.11;13:50;1008
```

For some calculation I need them in 1 minutes time frames.
So can somebody help me finding out, how I can interpolate the "missing" values, so that they fit in the present ones?

I used this command to get the Dataframe:

```
df <- read_delim("~/values.txt", ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(Date = col_date(format = "%d.%m.%y"), Value = col_double(), Time = col_time(format = "%H:%M")), trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: Have a look at `?approx`.

Comment: Do you need to know how to read the data file in? Do you know anything about date and time objects in R? Or data frames? When someone says "I am quite new" its hard to know where to begin if they dont include any code.

Comment: well, i have all data in a dataframe; i figuried this out, how to the the data from the csv file to a dataframe. with the colums Date, Time and Value. But now i need "additional" values between the given ones. this is the point where i stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deal with minute data, I would recommend using package `xts` and the function `na.approx` from package `zoo`. In a nutshell, you need to create an empty vector of minute data that you will `merge` with your original data. Then, you can use `na.approx` to approximate the missing values.

```
#Intial data, not by minute    
datetime <- Sys.time()
date_time_init <- Sys.time()+c(0,3,5,8)*60
df1 <- xts(c(1:4),date_time_init)
> df1
                    [,1]
2017-06-02 03:10:20    1
2017-06-02 03:13:20    2
2017-06-02 03:15:20    3
2017-06-02 03:18:20    4

#Create time sequence by minute
date_time_complete <- seq.POSIXt(from=min(date_time_init),
                                 to=max(date_time_init),by="min") 

#Merge initial data with new time sequence
df2 <- merge(df1,xts(,date_time_complete))
                    df1
2017-06-02 03:10:20   1
2017-06-02 03:11:20  NA
2017-06-02 03:12:20  NA
2017-06-02 03:13:20   2
2017-06-02 03:14:20  NA
2017-06-02 03:15:20   3
2017-06-02 03:16:20  NA
2017-06-02 03:17:20  NA
2017-06-02 03:18:20   4

na.approx(df2)
                         df1
2017-06-02 03:07:24 1.000000
2017-06-02 03:08:24 1.333333
2017-06-02 03:09:24 1.666667
2017-06-02 03:10:24 2.000000
2017-06-02 03:11:24 2.500000
2017-06-02 03:12:24 3.000000
2017-06-02 03:13:24 3.333333
2017-06-02 03:14:24 3.666667
2017-06-02 03:15:24 4.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you a) know how to read in data from a text file with semicolon delimiters. I would advise using `stringsAsFators=FALSE`. And b) know how to conjoin columns of text with `paste`. So with a dataframe like

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   35 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Dates: chr  "02.01.11" "02.01.11" "02.01.11" "02.01.11" ...
 $ Times: chr  "11:00" "11:05" "11:10" "11:15" ...
 $ Vals : int  576 552 672 720 336 408 288 228 288 288 ...
```

One can use the base function `approxfun` and give the paste()-ed Dates&Times to `as.POSIXct` to form the backbone of the solution:

```
dat$Datetimes <- with(dat, as.POSIXct( paste(Dates,Times), format="%m.%d.%y %H:%M") )
```

Now create a new dataframe starting with a sequence of "minute-points" made with `seq.POSIXct` spanning the range of the times:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(Mins = seq(min(dat$Datetimes), max(dat$Datetimes), by="1 min") )
```

And then use an the expression of the form: `approxfun( <inner args>)(<outer args>)` to make the linear interpolations in the missing intervals. `approxfun` returns a function based on the `<inner-args>` to which the "minute-points" are given as the `<outer-args>` :

```
dat2$interp <- approxfun(dat$Datetimes, dat$Vals)(dat2$Mins)
str(dat2)
#----------
'data.frame':   171 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Mins  : POSIXct, format: "2011-02-01 11:00:00" "2011-02-01 11:01:00" ...
 $ interp: num  576 571 566 562 557 ...
```

To "see" the results on the same scale:

```
with(dat, plot(Datetimes,Vals,col="red") )
with(dat2, points(Mins,interp ,cex=0.2))
```

[image]